# Can Xcode 5 compile Ada?

Tags: xcode5, ada, gnat

I use Xcode 3.0 to edit and build Ada projects. As I am also developing iOS apps on Xcode 5, I would like to move all Ada related work to Xcode 5 so that I open just one single version of Xcode. Switching between Xcode 3.0 and Xcode 5 is really troublesome.

Does anyone get Xcode 5 to compile Ada?

I tried http://homepage.mac.com/awreynolds/ but looks like website is already out of service. Macada.org is outdated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A digest of an [article](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.ada/_PBKHmbIl0Q/LBVMOFJDF8cJ) I posted on comp.lang.ada:

The consensus (see eg [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ada.macosx/1156)) was that there isn't a usable Xcode plugin for 
Ada. It does depend rather on your version of Xcode; the version [here](http://maxao.free.fr/xcode-ada-plugin/) 
only 'works' with Xcode 3.0.

I don’t develop iOS apps, so I’m happy with GNAT GPL from [AdaCore](http://libre.adacore.com) or FSF GCC [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuada/files/GNAT_GCC%20Mac%20OS%20X/4.8.1/), both with [Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com/).

A Google search found more recent work [here](https://github.com/phausler/XcodeAPI), [here](https://github.com/0xced/CLITool-InfoPlist), and [here](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode4-Plugin-Template) (the most recent). It looks as though you need to know Objective C to develop a plugin.

Comment: Does that mean the plugin development ceased at Xcode 3.x? Really love to use Xcode these days as it is the best IDE for me.

Comment: It seems like Apple haven’t released any details of the plugin API, aside possibly for some headers. I’ve added some links about more recent developments (not for Ada, sadly).

Comment: Thanks Simon. I will take a look at the links about developing plugin.